# Jekyll not generating files from deeply nested folder

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, static-site

I am trying to generate a site that contains javadoc.

The structure looks like this:

```
|
|--com
|   |--myproduct
|          |--mypackage
|               |--notgenerated.html
|--index.html
```

In the _site folder I get only

```
|
|--index.html
```

When I add a dummy file in the com directory

```
|
|--com
|   |--myproduct
|   |       |--mypackage
|   |            |--notgenerated.html
|   |--generated.html
|--index.html
```

The _site folder now looks like this

```
|
|--com
|   |--generated.html
|--index.html
```

How can I get Jekyll to copy these deeply nested files to the _site directory without having to place dummy files in the intermediate directories?

I am using Ruby 1.9.1 with Jekyll 0.11.2 on Win7-x64.

Comment: When you run jekyll, do you not get any error output at all? If so, paste it into the question...

Comment: Nope, no error output, and all other pages generate fine.

Comment: What are the actual names of the directories and the file? It may have something to do with that.

Comment: Folders beginning with an underscore, such as `_EXAMPLE`, need to be added to the `include` section of `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind souls at Github support found the cause.

It turns out that I had a mistake in `_config.yml`.

I used

```
exclude: dir1, dir2, file1
```

instead of

```
exclude: [dir1, dir2, file1]
```

And this caused the site generation to fail. Silently.